# How treat integral of an absolute value function, over a symmetric interval,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am computing Fourier coefficients for some function f and have a question about how to treat the integral of |x|*cos(nx), over the interval [-$\pi$, $\pi$].

Is there symmetry to apply here, before actually integrating, which I'm guessing requires integration by parts?

Can I just compute twice the integral from 0 to pi, and changing my integrand now to x*cos(nx)?  The graph of |x| makes me think that I can do this.

Thanks,

Edit: I can also easily verify that |x| is an even function.

Comment: Yes, you can do that because the function is even.

Comment: Ok, I'll start computing then.  Thanks @BolzWeir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $|x|$ is even, and $\cos(nx)$ is even. Thus,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x|\cos(nx) dx=2 \int_{0}^{\pi} |x|\cos(nx)dx =2 \int_{0}^{\pi} x\cos(nx)  dx$$

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to check the cos(nx) factor, @ethan!  Because now...I am going to compute the integral over the same interval of |x| * sin(nx).  How could I do this now?  Even * odd gives an odd function, so I can't use the even symmetry anymore.

Comment: hmnm...does an odd function just integrate to zero, when the integration is done on a symmetric interval? which means i don't have to compute anything at all for |x| sin(nx) .. @bolzweir

Comment: yea, i'm pretty sure it integrates to zero..

Comment: Yup, that sounds right.